# Proper way of designing functions with and without debug information in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When I design a function in a class, I want to balance the information I can extract from it. Some information may be useful for debug but not necessary as the output of the function. I give the following example:

```
class A
{
   bool my_func(int arg1, int &output, std::vector<int> &intermediate_vec);
  {
     // do something
  }
}
```

In the function `my_func`, `std::vector<int> &intermediate_vec` is not necessary as the only information I am interested in is stored in the variable `output`. However, for debug purpose I am also interested in obtaining `intermediate_vec` as it is not convenient to check this variable inside the function for some reason. Therefore, I am considering designing two functions inside class A, one is used for debug, and the other is for real application.

```
    class A
    {
       // for debug
       bool my_func(int arg1, int &output, std::vector<int> &intermediate_vec);
      {
         // do something
      }
      // invoked by other programs 
      bool my_func(int arg1, int &output);
      {
         // do something
        std::vector<int> intermediate_vec
        return my_func(arg1, output, intermediate_vec);
      }
    }
```

I am just wondering wheter there are better ways to do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Is `intermediate_vec` necessary for the logic of the function, or is it just there to collect some additional information that you wouldn't otherwise need? For example, would it make sense for the second version of your function to just declare an `intermediate_vec` and pass it to the first version?

Comment: @Vaughn Cato This is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: What are the downsides to your approach?

Comment: Compared to what @Sebastian Redl suggested, the downside is that I will have more functions than it is necessary.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato I have changed the codes.

Comment: You could make the first version protected, and then create a class `TestA` that derives from `A` and provides access to the first version for testing.

Comment: I'm assuming that the downside of having more functions is complicating the public interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a logging library and log those intermediate values at debug log level instead of collecting them as output.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using the `intermediate_vec` in some debug post-processing it can be tricky. However, if you only plan on using it just to print the results it easier.

The main thing I dislike in your idea is having `//do something`, which seem to do exactly the same, in two different places. This is very error-prone and starts to grow into a real PIA, when you will have to maintain a dozen classes with a dozen methods, and half of them have some debug copy-cat. Every change in logic has to be done twice in a coherent manner.

When I came upon a similar problem I was considering following things, to avoid doubling logic while performing conditional logging and/or additional instrumentation.

**`#define DEBUG/NDEBUG`**
You just have one copy of code with some pre-processor conditionals.

**`template < int DEBUG >`**. 
Basically the same effect but different semantics.

The template method might complicate the coding a little bit, but it will allow to use both version during the run-time which might come in handy. The `#define` method does not alter API at all but you really need to think when designing code if you want some fancy selective or multilevel debugging.

The **two functions** method was ok in my use-cases when I had to have safe version and fast version of routine. The safe did some checks and then called fast number cruncher. This was useful if the number cruncher was used in loops or internally where it was safe to assume you can skip checks.

If the debug version is slower (e.g. 'casue you need to initialize and fill a long vector), then you probably do not want to call it in a release code. The same goes for logging. If you really need to output one number, but in the debug version you will end up printing megabytes of data (e.g. calculating a norm of a vector and printing the vector itself), you will want to use conditional logging.

So in overall this would look more like this:

```
class A
{
    bool my_func(int arg1, int &output, std::vector<int> &intermediate_vec);
  {
      if(DEBUG) {//fill in the vector}
      // do something
      if(DEBUG) {//print out some fancy stuff}

  }
  // invoked by other programs 
  bool my_func(int arg1, int &output);
  {
    std::vector<int> intermediate_vec;
    return my_func(arg1, output, intermediate_vec);
  }
}
```

Of course then you can use short-call with the debug, but you won't get the vector back. Or full-call in no-debug mode, however the `intermediate_vec` will not be meaningful.

Anything to avoid copy-pasting application logic stuff. I did it and I was very miserable when it came to changing the logic.